# 2d barcode reader Java ME sdk

Tags: java-me, sdk, barcode, qr-code

Does anyone know a good sdk for reading and decoding 2d barcodes (preferably Datamatrix or QR) from within a Java ME application? The application will be closed source, and while I'd prefer that the SDK be free (perhaps MIT or LGPL licenses), I would not mind forking over some cash for a commercial license. I've come across the [Semacode](http://semacode.com) SDK but it's GPL licensed and the links to the commercially licensed version do not seem to be working. There's also one from http://qrcode.sourceforge.jp but it's also GPL licensed and has sparse documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The only promising one I could find was [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

Comment: Thanks Arnold. Have you actually tried using it in a mobile app? What are the success rates in decoding? A very rough x out of 10 figure will do. The Apache license is perfect but they don't officially support j2me usage. I'm primarily a php developer and I don't know much about porting j2se code to j2me code, if that's even necessary. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't actually used it. Your question caught my eye because I had to find a barcode _generator_ for Java once. After reading your question and saw that you wanted a decoder, I was curious enough to look around to see what was out there and try to help.

Comment: I appreciate it. I'll give zxing a shot.

Comment: I am also working in a J2ME project with Zxing, I can say that for QR and barcodes is ok, but for Datamatrix, is very disappointing because it only works for clean images generated by code, not captured by a camera. Pls if you find a different option, tell me sth, I would need a valid solution.