# How to read a Barcode.. any particular API ? i need in the J2ME 

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, barcode

Please suggest a API that can let me do the barcode read in mobile for J2ME..

Comment: see this [link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483468/2d-barcode-reader-java-me-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

There's a related post on doing this on Android: [Using ZXing to create an android barcode scanning app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050263/using-zxing-to-create-an-android-barcode-scanning-app)

Update: As bhakki pointed out, you are asking about J2ME. The ZXing library appears to have partial support for J2ME: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/, so this other post may be of use still.  Of course, this assumes you are using a mobile device with a camera

Update2: Specific J2ME code can be found in their SVN repository: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fjavame%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fzxing%2Fclient%2Fj2me%253Fstate%253Dclosed ... and their forums may be of use: https://groups.google.com/group/zxing/search?group=zxing&q=javame&qt_g=Search+this+group

Comment: he asking in j2me not in android.

Comment: @bhakki: good point, not all java created equal.. It does appear that ZXing is at least partially supported by J2ME.. I'll clarify my post on this point.

Comment: i just saw ZXing site which u have posted.  didnt find much on J2ME. they do support partially but didnt find .jar for J2ME programming in their downloads page. any others suggestions guys....?

Comment: They have a bunch of Java files in their source branch.. maybe that'll be of use: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fjavame%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fzxing%2Fclient%2Fj2me%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Comment: What about sending the image to a server and do the processing there?